# Using NHibernate LINQ, Is it possible to put a .Where() clause after a .ThenFetch()

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I understand that in NHibernate LINQ, you need to have the fetches at the end of your code but how would you filter on something that is loaded via a `ThenFetch`?

Here is an example

```
   IEnumerable<Project> list = Session.Query<Project>()
                                      .FetchMany(r => r.ProjectSponsors)
                                      .ThenFetch(r => r.Sponsor)
                                      .Where(r => !r.Name == "Joe");
```

this above doens't work as it throws a `NotSupportedException`.

Any ideas on the right way to implement the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No currently it isn't. `Fetch` can only be used as last statement.

Comment: so is there anyway to do this query so i can do a filter on the Sponsor.Name field ?? Any workaround or other format?  i updated the query to be a little clearer

Comment: Query<P>().Where(p => p.PS.Any(ps => ps.Name != "Joe")).Fetches()